# Trouble updating rows of data in an External Content Type using Javascript

Tags: 2010, javascript, caml, external-content-type

I've tried a few different ways of doing this, including querying the `External Content Type` and then updating the current item. However as far as I ever get is an `undefined variable error`.

This is my current code:

```
function itemupdate() {
//var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("sp_rev");
var sp_rev = document.querySelectorAll('.sp_rev')
var sp_ap = document.querySelectorAll('.sp_ap')
var sp_com = document.querySelectorAll('.sp_com')
var siteUrl = '/sites/xxx/xxx/';
var context = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('XXXXX');
for(var i = 0; i<sp_rev.length; i++) {
  //    alert(sp_rev[i].id + " : " + sp_rev[i].value + " - " + sp_ap[i].value + " - " + sp_com[i].checked);
  var curId = sp_rev[i].id
  var queryXml = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name = 'ID'/><Value Type='Text'>" + curId + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>";
  var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
  query.set_viewXml(queryXml);
  var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
  var items = oList.getItems(query);
  context.load(items);
  context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.UpdateItem), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailedUpdate));
}
}

function onQueryFailedUpdate(sender, args) {
  alert(args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}    

function UpdateItem(sender, args) {
  var resultsEnumerator = context.getEnumerator();
  while (resultsEnumerator.moveNext()) {
    var currentItem = resultsEnumerator.get_current();
    alert(currentItem);
  } 
}
```

I get below error.

> `context is undefined`.

UPDATE: 02/12/15

I have updated my code thanks to input/comments from here and other developers to this:

```
function itemupdate() {

var sp_rev = document.querySelectorAll('.sp_rev')
var sp_ap = document.querySelectorAll('.sp_ap')
var sp_com = document.querySelectorAll('.sp_com')

var siteUrl = '/xx/xx/xx';
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('xxxx');

for (var i = 0; i < sp_rev.length; i++) {
    (function (id, ctx) {
        var curId = sp_rev[i].id
        var queryXml = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name = 'ID'/><Value Type='Number'>" + curId + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>";
        var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
        query.set_viewXml(queryXml);
        this.items = oList.getItems(query);
        ctx.load(items);
        ctx.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, function () {
            var resultsEnumerator = items.getEnumerator();
            while (resultsEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                var currentItem = resultsEnumerator.get_current();
                alert(currentItem);
            }
        }), Function.createDelegate(this, function (s, args) {
            alert(args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
        }));
    })(i, clientContext);
}
;
}
```

Now I am getting a response back, however it is failing and giving me the following error:

> `The given key was not present in the dictionary. undefined`.

Comment: Can you try executing your code inside `SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function () {
                    //Your code goes here
                });`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
```

for the current site

You also use `clientContext` instead of `context` in the next line

Forget about the whole code (and using `alert()`)
Open F12 Developer tools and make the one line in the console work:

```
new SP.ClientContext( '.....' );
```

Answer (score 0):

For executing **JSOM**, we need to delay until some scripts are loaded. The definition of [SP.ClientContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245896.aspx) is in `sp.js`. So it must be loaded at first and thereafter we can execute our **JSOM**.

In **SharePoint 2010**

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(functionTobeCalledNext, "sp.js");
```

In **SharePoint 2013**

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function () { 
// code goes here
 });
```

I believe it will solve the problem.